# Fastest way to search for a String in a substring in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

Currently I am working on a Kattis problem, "String Matching"(https://open.kattis.com/problems/stringmatching). I am getting correct output for my program, however since the file is so big, and the time limit for completing the problem is 2 seconds I keep getting the "Time Limit Exceeded" error on Kattis. I've attempted two ways to solve the problem and the second test case exceeds my time limit on both. Here is what I have done:

```
    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        String pattern = sc.nextLine();
        String text = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < text.length()-pattern.length()+1; i++) {
            if(text.regionMatches(i,  pattern, 0, pattern.length())) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
    while(sc.hasNext()) {

        String pattern = sc.nextLine();
        String text = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < text.length()-pattern.length()+1; i++) {
            if(pattern.equals(text.substring(i, i+pattern.length()))) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }   
    System.out.println();
}
```

What is a faster way to take a String and compare it to see if it exists in a larger String?

Comment: Use the String method Contains()? Or use RegularExpressions

Comment: But can I somehow use .contains() and output the index at where each occurrence begins?

Comment: Speaking about time-complexity, you can implement [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) to match patterns in texts. It surely will increase efficiency, expecially when working with long and repetitive strings.

Comment: Did you try with `String.indexOf()`? Solutions using a regular expression are expensive because you only need to use each pattern once.

Comment: Regular expressions are awesome, but slow for time-intensive purposes.  If speed of execution is the most important thing, you might consider doing the matching yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment on getting the positions, it's pretty straightforward with a regex matcher. See below:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("your regex pattern here");
Matcher m = p.matcher("the string you're testing");
if (m.find()) {
    int start = m.start();
    int end = m.end();

    // do something
}
```

EDIT: A working example below.

```
public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
    printMatchInfo("\\w+", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
}

private static void printMatchInfo(String regex, String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    System.out.println(String.format("Checking %s against %s", input, regex)); 
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Found %s with (start, end) (%d, %d)", m.group(), m.start(), m.end()));
    }
}
```

Output

```
Checking The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog against \w+
Found The with (start, end) (0, 3)
Found quick with (start, end) (4, 9)
Found brown with (start, end) (10, 15)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution for case of massive data would give [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) or [Suffix Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

Naive implementation of suffix tree is pretty simple, you can check my solution here: https://github.com/sergpank/lcs/blob/master/src/MonoMain.java

If you need to build Suffix Tree faster, try Ukkonen Algorythm or any other advanced data structure.